# Wrapper on shmctl with shmid 0 to cleanup shared memory segments

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-memory

I have written a wrapper function on shmctl to destroy shared memory segment. I just need to ensure that segment is deleted gracefully. So wrote below lines of code. But I wonder why shmid of 0 is invalid value and we need to abort()?

```
shmctl_wrap( int shmid, int cmd, shmid_ds buf)
{
    if( cmd == IPC_RMID && shmid == 0 && buf->shm_nattch != 0)
        abort();
    rc = shmctl( shmid, cmd, buf);
    return rc;
}
```

But my system aborts at some peculiar case which I am not able to debug.  Not sure if my wrapper is serving the purpose.

What I need to know is

1. In which case I get shmid as 0.
2. Also what extra measures need to be taken to make sure that segment is destroyed when shmid is 0.

If shmid is not valid value, then I see the segment which is already created with that value,

**ipcs -m**

------ Shared Memory Segments --------

**key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status**

0x0001ff07 **0**          root       666        632004     73
0x00000000 32769      root       0          512        0
0x00008000 65538      root       0          430044     41
0x00000000 196611     root       666        8136       2
0x00008001 131076     root       42         430044     41
0x00008002 229381     root       775        430044     1
0x00008003 262150     root       336        430044     1

Comment: According to svipc man page of Linux http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html  - "positive integer (its shmid)" - so I understand this as valid shmid are 1 and greater, no 0.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from 'printing' the arguments of your wrapper to figure out why your wrapper is abort'ing?

Comment: Ofcourse JC1, my wrapper is aborting because it satisfies the if condition. My concern is, why should we abort when shmid is 0. Isn't it a valid value?